# Словообразование

Tags: словообразование

Интерфиксы, которые соединяют два корня, являются  словоизменительной или словообразовательной морфемой? Или это всё же стяжка? Если это всего лишь стяжка, то как объяснить, каким способом, например, образовалось слово "луноход"?

Answer (score 1):

Интерфикс — морфема **словообразовательная**. Только соединяет он, конечно же, не два корня, а две основы либо основу и целое слово. А слово *луноход* образовалось **суффиксально-сложным** способом (его ещё называют **сложение с суффиксацией**). Интерфикс здесь является **частью** словообразовательного форманта, наряду с суффиксом (нулевым).

Answer (score 0):

Очень хороший ответ!